# Read data from Spark checkpoint directory

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to read values from spark checkpoint directory .
Does checkpoint only stores data in HDFS?
I want to check actually the data exists in checkpoint or not.I am using my local machine to run Spark and test to understand the concept.

```
    public static JavaStreamingContext createContext(){      
   SparkConfsparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkStreaming");   
   sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]");         
   JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(20)); 
   jssc.checkpoint("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test");       
 JavaDStream<String> customReceiverStream = jssc.receiverStream(new
     JavaCustomReceiver(MYSQL_DRIVER,
     MYSQL_CONNECTION_URL,MYSQL_USERNAME,MYSQL_PWD));

   return jssc;  
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Function0<JavaStreamingContext> createContextFunc = new Function0<JavaStreamingContext>() {
        @Override
        public JavaStreamingContext call() {
            return createContext();
        }
    };

    JavaStreamingContext streamingContext = JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate("C:\\Users\\dhala\\Desktop\\test", createContextFunc);
    System.out.println(streamingContext.toString());
    System.out.println(streamingContext.sparkContext().getCheckpointDir());
    streamingContext.start();
    streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```

I want to read from the checkpoint dir..How do I find the actuall value stored in checkpoints

Comment: Does checkpoint only stores data in HDFS? it depends where you are running job and configurations. In your case streaming engine will generate streaming metadata files inside `C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test` and you can manually browse that directory as well.